# SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected character at line 1 column 1 of the JSON data - but JSON validator indicates "valid json"

Tags: google-visualization

I'm trying to render a scatter chart with Google Charts. I populate the datatable with a JSON string that I get from a servlet. But the scatter plot won't render, but only throw an error message:

> SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected character at line 1 column 1 of
>   the JSON data

It happens during the data.addRows( JSON.parse(array) ); segment. JSON validators can't find any errors.

That's my code:

```
    <script >


  var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
  var array;
  xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {

      if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
            array = this.responseText;    
      }      
  };

  xmlhttp.open("GET", "/sifa/faces/jsonGenerator", true);
  xmlhttp.send();



    google.charts.load("current", {packages:["corechart"]});
    google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

    function drawChart() {

        var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
        data.addColumn('number', 'x');
        data.addColumn('number', 'y');
        data.addColumn({type: 'string', role: 'annotation'});


        data.addRows( JSON.parse(array) );


      var options = {
        legend: 'none',
        colors: ['#087037'],        
        selectionMode: 'single',       
        tooltip: {trigger: 'selection'},
        pointSize: 12,
        animation: {
          duration: 200,
          easing: 'inAndOut',
        },
        explorer: { 
            actions: ['dragToZoom', 'rightClickToReset'],            
            keepInBounds: true,
            maxZoomIn: 4.0,
          colors: ['#D44E41']
        }
     };


      var chart = new google.visualization.ScatterChart(document.getElementById('animatedshapes_div'));

      chart.draw(data, options);

    }



    </script>
```

The JSON string looks like that:

> {"rows":[{ "c":[{"v":-0.559},{"v":0.93},{"v":"100-00-5"}]}, {"c":[{"v":0.387},{"v":0.347},{"v":"100-01-6"}]}, {"c":[{"v":-1.88},{"v":0.712},{"v":"100-02-7"}]}, {"c":[{"v":-0.038},{"v":0.701},{"v":"100-06-1"}]}, {"c":[{"v":0.451},{"v":0.321},{"v":"100-07-2"}]}, {"c":[{"v":1.51},{"v":-1.37},{"v":"100-09-4"}]}, {"c":[{"v":0.756},{"v":-0.026},{"v":"100-10-7"}]}, {"c":[{"v":-0.851},{"v":-0.135},{"v":"100-15-2"}]}, {"c":[{"v":0.456},{"v":0.038},{"v":"100-18-5"}]}, {"c":[{"v":-0.117},{"v":0.847},{"v":"100-20-9"}]}, {"c":[{"v":1.97},{"v":-0.568},{"v":"100-21-0"}]}, {"c":[{"v":-0.122},{"v":0.85},{"v":"100-36-7"}]}, {"c":[{"v":1.52},{"v":-0.432},{"v":"100-37-8"}]}, {"c":[{"v":-0.72},{"v":0.895},{"v":"100-39-0"}]}, {"c":[{"v":-2.03},{"v":0.285},{"v":"100-40-3"}]}, {"c":[{"v":1.07},{"v":-0.191},{"v":"100-41-4"}]}, {"c":[{"v":1.68},{"v":-0.374},{"v":"100-42-5"}]}, {"c":[{"v":-0.744},{"v":0.186},{"v":"100-43-6"}]}, {"c":[{"v":0.143},{"v":0.644},{"v":"100-44-7"}]}, {"c":[{"v":1.35},{"v":-0.252},{"v":"100-46-9"}]}, {"c":[{"v":-0.026},{"v":0.658},{"v":"100-47-0"}]}, {"c":[{"v":-2.02},{"v":-0.089},{"v":"100-48-1"}]}, {"c":[{"v":-0.481},{"v":0.983},{"v":"100-50-5"}]}, {"c":[{"v":2.44},{"v":-0.692},{"v":"100-51-6"}]}, {"c":[{"v":0.573},{"v":-0.08},{"v":"100-52-7"}]}, {"c":[{"v":-1.64},{"v":0.776},{"v":"100-54-9"}]}, {"c":[{"v":0.811},{"v":-0.112},{"v":"100-55-0"}]}, {"c":[{"v":-2.0},{"v":0.655},{"v":"100-58-3"}]}, {"c":[{"v":-2.03},{"v":0.211},{"v":"100-59-4"}]}, {"c":[{"v":-2.27},{"v":0.385},{"v":"100-60-7"}]}, {"c":[{"v":0.384},{"v":0.185},{"v":"100-61-8"}]}, {"c":[{"v":-0.887},{"v":0.96},{"v":"100-63-0"}]}, {"c":[{"v":-0.694},{"v":-0.252},{"v":"100-64-1"}]}, {"c":[{"v":0.105},{"v":0.542},{"v":"100-66-3"}]}, {"c":[{"v":-0.136},{"v":0.847},{"v":"100-68-5"}]}, {"c":[{"v":-0.234},{"v":0.828},{"v":"100-69-6"}]}, {"c":[{"v":-2.11},{"v":-0.05},{"v":"100-70-9"}]}, {"c":[{"v":-1.31},{"v":1.4},{"v":"100-71-0"}]}, {"c":[{"v":1.22},{"v":-0.177},{"v":"100-74-3"}]}, {"c":[{"v":1.81},{"v":-1.35},{"v":"100-79-8"}]}, {"c":[{"v":-1.16},{"v":1.04},{"v":"100-83-4"}]}, {"c":[{"v":-1.04},{"v":-0.536},{"v":"100-85-6"}]}, {"c":[{"v":1.65},{"v":-1.53},{"v":"100-86-7"}]}, {"c":[{"v":1.42},{"v":-0.339},{"v":"100-97-0"}]}, {"c":[{"v":-0.057},{"v":0.723},{"v":"100-99-2"}]}, {"c":[{"v":-0.056},{"v":0.675},{"v":"1000777-61-6"}]}, {"c":[{"v":0.663},{"v":-0.192},{"v":"1000817-22-0"}]}, {"c":[{"v":2.6},{"v":-0.64},{"v":"100085-61-8"}]}, {"c":[{"v":0.787},{"v":-0.044},{"v":"1001254-87-0"}]}, {"c":[{"v":-0.779},{"v":0.125},{"v":"1001320-38-2"}]}, {"c":[{"v":-2.24},{"v":-0.708},{"v":"100134-82-5"}]}, {"c":[{"v":1.19},{"v":-0.336},{"v":"1001354-72-8"}]}, {"c":[{"v":0.497},{"v":0.033},{"v":"1001416-18-7"}]}, {"c":[{"v":1.54},{"v":-0.968},{"v":"10016-20-3"}]}, {"c":[{"v":-1.49},{"v":-0.344},{"v":"1002-67-1"}]}, {"c":[{"v":2.73},{"v":-0.659},{"v":"100208-62-6"}]}, {"c":[{"v":-1.9},{"v":-0.373},{"v":"100208-66-0"}]}, {"c":[{"v":1.04},{"v":0.564},{"v":"100208-97-7"}]}, {"c":[{"v":2.55},{"v":-0.662},{"v":"100209-45-8"}]}, {"c":[{"v":-1.68},{"v":0.731},{"v":"100209-50-5"}]}, {"c":[{"v":0.872},{"v":-3.71},{"v":"10022-28-3"}]}, {"c":[{"v":0.275},{"v":0.301},{"v":"10022-31-8"}]}, {"c":[{"v":-0.087},{"v":0.476},{"v":"10022-68-1"}]}, {"c":[{"v":0.26},{"v":0.205},{"v":"10023-48-0"}]}, {"c":[{"v":0.479},{"v":0.03},{"v":"10024-93-8"}]}, {"c":[{"v":0.451},{"v":-0.011},{"v":"10024-97-2"}]}, {"c":[{"v":0.049},{"v":0.772},{"v":"10025-67-9"}]}, {"c":[{"v":0.792},{"v":0.032},{"v":"10025-70-4"}]}, {"c":[{"v":0.512},{"v":0.269},{"v":"10025-73-7"}]}, {"c":[{"v":2.13},{"v":-0.504},{"v":"10025-77-1"}]}, {"c":[{"v":0.215},{"v":0.615},{"v":"10025-78-2"}]}, {"c":[{"v":-2.23},{"v":0.287},{"v":"10025-82-8"}]}, {"c":[{"v":0.766},{"v":0.065},{"v":"10025-84-0"}]}, {"c":[{"v":0.675},{"v":0.128},{"v":"10025-87-3"}]}, {"c":[{"v":-2.01},{"v":0.623},{"v":"10025-91-9"}]}, {"c":[{"v":-0.134},{"v":0.667},{"v":"10025-99-7"}]}, {"c":[{"v":0.419},{"v":0.423},{"v":"10026-04-7"}]}, {"c":[{"v":0.428},{"v":0.279},{"v":"10026-06-9"}]}, {"c":[{"v":-0.549},{"v":0.752},{"v":"10026-11-6"}]}, {"c":[{"v":-0.082},{"v":0.527},{"v":"10026-12-7"}]}, {"c":[{"v":-1.18},{"v":1.11},{"v":"10026-13-8"}]}, {"c":[{"v":1.24},{"v":-0.105},{"v":"10026-22-9"}]}, {"c":[{"v":1.4},{"v":-0.15},{"v":"10026-24-1"}]}, {"c":[{"v":-2.68},{"v":0.853},{"v":"100276-37-7"}]}, {"c":[{"v":-1.86},{"v":-0.128},{"v":"10028-15-6"}]}, {"c":[{"v":-0.495},{"v":0.067},{"v":"10028-18-9"}]}, {"c":[{"v":2.14},{"v":-0.513},{"v":"10028-22-5"}]}, {"c":[{"v":-0.065},{"v":0.817},{"v":"1003-03-8"}]}, {"c":[{"v":-2.2},{"v":-0.657},{"v":"1003-09-4"}]}, {"c":[{"v":0.125},{"v":0.32},{"v":"1003-14-1"}]}, {"c":[{"v":-1.6},{"v":-0.16},{"v":"1003-52-7"}]}, {"c":[{"v":-0.58},{"v":0.798},{"v":"1003-68-5"}]}, {"c":[{"v":2.13},{"v":-0.48},{"v":"10031-43-3"}]}, {"c":[{"v":-2.01},{"v":-0.09},{"v":"1003218-40-3"}]}, {"c":[{"v":-2.03},{"v":0.044},{"v":"1003315-69-2"}]}, {"c":[{"v":-2.13},{"v":-0.068},{"v":"10034-85-2"}]}, {"c":[{"v":2.0},{"v":-0.554},{"v":"10034-88-5"}]}, {"c":[{"v":2.44},{"v":-0.578},{"v":"10034-96-5"}]}, {"c":[{"v":2.04},{"v":-0.52},{"v":"10035-04-8"}]}, {"c":[{"v":0.149},{"v":0.516},{"v":"10035-06-0"}]}, {"c":[{"v":0.106},{"v":0.667},{"v":"10035-10-6"}]}, {"c":[{"v":-2.08},{"v":0.914},{"v":"10038-98-9"}]}, {"c":[{"v":-1.14},{"v":1.47},{"v":"1003859-14-0"}]}, {"c":[{"v":0.638},{"v":-0.066},{"v":"10039-33-5"}]}, {"c":[{"v":0.632},{"v":0.113},{"v":"10039-54-0"}]}, {"c":[{"v":0.465},{"v":-0.165},{"v":"100402-60-6"}]}, {"c":[{"v":0.347},{"v":-0.227},{"v":"100418-33-5"}]}, {"c":[{"v":1.53},{"v":-0.681},{"v":"10042-59-8"}]}, {"c":[{"v":0.796},{"v":0.04},{"v":"10042-76-9"}]}, {"c":[{"v":-0.059},{"v":0.674},{"v":"1004297-30-6"}]}, {"c":[{"v":2.25},{"v":-0.553},{"v":"10043-01-3"}]}, {"c":[{"v":2.46},{"v":-0.558},{"v":"10043-11-5"}]}, {"c":[{"v":-0.845},{"v":-0.047},{"v":"10043-27-3"}]}, {"c":[{"v":2.72},{"v":-0.654},{"v":"10043-35-3"}]}, {"c":[{"v":2.04},{"v":-0.52},{"v":"10043-52-4"}]}, {"c":[{"v":2.58},{"v":-0.673},{"v":"10043-67-1"}]}, {"c":[{"v":0.103},{"v":0.159},{"v":"10043-84-2"}]}, {"c":[{"v":-2.44},{"v":1.15},{"v":"100442-33-9"}]}, {"c":[{"v":2.22},{"v":-0.477},{"v":"10045-86-0"}]}, {"c":[{"v":0.845},{"v":-0.117},{"v":"10045-89-3"}]}, {"c":[{"v":-0.601},{"v":1.17},{"v":"10045-95-1"}]}, {"c":[{"v":-1.3},{"v":1.42},{"v":"100453-11-0"}]}, {"c":[{"v":-2.49},{"v":0.931},{"v":"100485-51-6"}]}, {"c":[{"v":-0.041},{"v":0.729},{"v":"10049-04-4"}]}, {"c":[{"v":1.54},{"v":-0.69},{"v":"10049-36-2"}]}, {"c":[{"v":-2.01},{"v":-0.17},{"v":"100499-89-6"}]}, {"c":[{"v":-2.68},{"v":0.892},{"v":"100501-62-0"}]}, {"c":[{"v":1.32},{"v":-0.216},{"v":"100545-48-0"}]}, {"c":[{"v":1.66},{"v":0.857},{"v":"100556-82-9"}]}, {"c":[{"v":2.26},{"v":-0.616},{"v":"10058-44-3"}]}, {"c":[{"v":-0.902},{"v":0.524},{"v":"1006-23-1"}]}, {"c":[{"v":0.511},{"v":0.268},{"v":"10060-12-5"}]}, {"c":[{"v":-2.49},{"v":0.929},{"v":"10061-01-5"}]} ]}

Is there any mistake that I did not see?

Comment: Hi have you tried opening the file in a text editor and checking for a UTF8 byte order mark? BOM?

Comment: When I browse my jsonGenerator and save the file with the JSON that firefox shows me and open it with notepad++, it says UTF-8 coding (no BOM). 

At the moment I set up the column names manually in the code. I changed it to declare it in the JSON as well, validated the JSON string successfully but the error is still there.

Comment: However, I just took the string and C&Ped it to the constructor of the datatable and suddenly it works just fine. But not if get it from the Ajax reply and then encode it.

Comment: In another thread with a similar problem, a comment suggested to set the datatype of the response from JSON to html. I tried this and .... it works. Both, with text/html and text/plain.

Comment: if the response type is JSON, then you don't need `JSON.parse`, because it is already parsed as JSON. that's why setting to text works.